# Converting Jython htmlunit script to pure Java

Tags: java, jython, htmlunit

I have a script for [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython) that works perfectly, but it's really really slow, so I decided to try to see if I can convert it to pure java and see if it speeds it up.

In Jython I am using:

```
from java.util import logging
from java import lang
from org.apache.commons.logging import LogFactory
logger = LogFactory.getLog('com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit')
logger.getLogger().setLevel(logging.Level.OFF)
webclient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6)
webclient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(False)
```

This basically prevents all the annoying warning messages from htmlunit to stop coming on the screen (it tends to complain a lot if the code it's reading isn't perfect but still ends up reading it).

In Java I tried to copy and paste the same code, but Java seems to ignore it.  If I add types to my import, it doesn't give me an error it just keeps doing the same thing.

```
import java import.lang;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
LogFactory.getLog('com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit');
LogFactory.getLogger().setLevel(logging.Level.OFF);
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Since the file is fairly large and I'll have to do quite a been of converting of code, what is the logic of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I really doubt you'd get much improvement from converting, given that Jython runs on JVM too... one can believe, of course.

Comment: I was reading this article: http://blog.dhananjaynene.com/2008/07/performance-comparison-c-java-python-ruby-jython-jruby-groovy/ and they mentioned how the same script took 1.6 seconds to complete within pure java versus 632 in jython.  I don't know if i'll get that big of a performance increase but in jython to parse a page took over 2 minutes, so far it takes about 24 seconds in java(granted its not the exact same yet but even if it takes a little more i think I'll be happy). current parsing about 16,000 pages has taken over 18 days for me in jython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's Syntax is not equal to Python's Syntax. imports are declared on the top of the Class-File, other things are done within the "class"-container.

Basically a Java file looks something like this:

```
import [...]
public class YourClass{

  public YourClass(){
    // Constructor
  }

  public static void main(Stirng[] args){
    // The method Java calls when a class is executed in a JVM
  }
}
```

You should check out some Java-Tutorials first, because Java and Python are quite different.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll check it out.  I thought because I was importing java modules into jython that I was actually using java syntax.